# Meteorite hunters Search for FIREBALLS

Tags: astrophysics, atmospheric-science, meteors, meteorites

normally meteorite hunters search for fireballs....but they totally ignore meteor showers . why so?

as far as i can think meteors in meteor showers are usually produced by small particles so they burn up quickly in the upper atmosphere about 30-100 km in .
but fireballs are caused by larger objects which may not completely burn up in the atmosphere.hence making fireballs a reasonable starting point to search

any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the whole reason. We have good evidence that meteor showers are caused by lots of tiny pieces of fluffy comet detritus, which has no chance of reaching the ground; a bright bolide, however, is much more likely to have a substantial rocky or metallic mass.